# is there any way to find the exit for loop if?

Tags: robotframework

expected result: click the button in 4 items which one is match to the statement

actual result:Exit For Loop If' expected 1 argument, got 2.

```
[Arguments]    ${CardName}
    ${elements} =    Get Webelements    css:.card-title
    ${index}=   Set Variable    1
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
         Log    ${element.text}
        Exit For Loop If        '${CardName}' ==  '${element.text}'
        ${index}=   Evaluate    ${index}  + 1
    END
    Click Button    xpath:(//*[@class='card-footer'])[${index}]/button
```

error:Keyword 'BuiltIn.Exit For Loop If' expected 1 argument, got 2.

Comment: You seem to have two spaces in line 
`Exit For Loop If        '${CardName}' ==  '${element.text}'`.
two spaces is enough for robotframework to consider that 2 arguments.